# Can't get POST data from an API callback

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the POST data that is being sent to a controller method within my CI project. However, I am not able to get this data which ever way I try to get it.

I have checked NGROK Inspect and Im able to see the data that I want as you can see in the screenshot below:
[image]

The problem is when I try to access this date from the controller method itself, I get nothing, not sure if Im accessing it wrong, but the following are what I have tried:

```
$Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); //Method 1

$response = $this->input->post("Body"); // Method 2

$data = $this->input->post(); //Method 3
```

I get nothing whenever I try to use the methods above.
This is how the Controller method looks like, basically, it creates a json file and saves the response there:

```
    public function resolve_payment(){
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $fp = fopen("testdir.json", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: This cost me an hour when I developed my first API endpoint using CI. It may or may not be your case: try disabling CSRF protection for the controller/method that's supposed to receive the POST data

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it, CSRF protection is already off in the config file

Comment: What is the form encoding of your post? If it is multipart/form-data you're not going to be able to use php://input unless you change it to something else (at least temporarily for debugging). Also, have you tried checking the contents of php://input *before* you json_decode it? Json_decode will return empty if there is any sort of issue.

Comment: @NoelOmondi I'm assuming here that the POST you're getting is not a response to a request but a regular POST request coming into your endpoint. Am I correct? Have you tried outputting or otherwise writing a log with `var_dump($_POST)` and see if there's anything there? I know CI's `$this->input->post()` should wrap the same info as `$_POST` but for the sake of debugging it could give us some pointers